# How to add the text to germ-rect and ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I would like to add the text to plotly. for example, the code could not add the mytext to the ply.test plot? Anyone can give helps. Thanks!

```
test.dat <- data.frame(xmin=c(0,1.5), ymin=c(-1,-1), xmax=c(1,2), ymax=c(1,1),        col=c("blue", "red"))
ggp.test <- ggplot() + geom_rect(data=test.dat, aes(xmin=xmin, ymin=ymin,    xmax=xmax, ymax=ymax, group = col), fill=test.dat$col) + theme_bw()
ggp.test

# How to add the text as hoverinfo?
ply.test <- plotly_build(ggp.test)
ply.test
mytext <- paste(test.dat$xmin,test.dat$ymin,sep = "")
style(ply.test, text = mytext, hoverinfo = "text", traces = c(0,1 ))
```

Comment: Try to change the last line of code to `traces = c(1,2)`

Comment: Just change the traces. It did not work.

Comment: Do you want to add text in mytext to the plot or do you want this text to appear once you hover over the bar?

Comment: Yes, i want this my text to appear once the hover over the bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following codes works for me:

```
library(plotly)

test.dat <- data.frame(
 xmin=c(0,1.5), xmax=c(1,2),
 ymin=c(-1,-1), ymax=c(1,1), col=c("blue", "red") )

ggp.test <- ggplot(data=test.dat, 
 aes(xmin=xmin, ymin=ymin, xmax=xmax, ymax=ymax, group = col) ) +
  geom_rect(fill=test.dat$col) +
  theme_bw()

ply.test <- plotly_build(ggp.test)
mytext <- paste(test.dat$xmin,test.dat$ymin,sep = "")
style(ply.test, text = mytext, hoverinfo = "text", traces = c(1,2))
```

It produces this:

[image]

Comment: Oh, my god,  why I only got the trace 0 , 1 to appear once the hover over the bar. the same code

Comment: Hi Lstat, another question. if i have many bars and want to add individual name to each bar, How can i do? Until now, the hoverinfo seems to be depend on the groups.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your request. Renaming each in `mytext` would work? Then using `traces=seq(lenght(mytext))` to activate all of them automatically.